# Material UI Dialog not closing when clicking the overlay

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog

I have created a reusable dialog/modal using React and Material UI.
When I try to click the overlay, something weird happens.
Instead of closing the modal and setting 'open' to false, the scripts directly sets open to true again for some reason.

The handleClickOpen is triggered when clicking the overlay and I can't find the problem causing this.

Dialog component:

```
    const { onClose, open } = props;

    const handleClose = () => {
        onClose();
    };

    const preventDef = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
    };

    return (
        <Dialog open={open} onClose={onClose} className={className} onClick={handleClose}>
            <Container>
                <Grid container className={`${className}__container`}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={props.colsAmount} onClick={preventDef} className={`${className}__column`}>
                        {props.component}

                        {props.closeButton && (
                            <div className={`${className}__close`} onClick={handleClose}>
                                <Close />
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Container>
        </Dialog>
    );
```

The component I load and trigger the dialog in:

```
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleClose = (e) => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    return (
        <div className={[classes.ShopCard]} onClick={handleClickOpen}>
            <div className={`${classes.ShopCard}__image`}>
                <div className={`${classes.ShopCard}__image__wrapper`}>
                    <img src={image} alt={alt} />

                    <div className={`${classes.ShopCard}__image__price`}>Vanaf €{price}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className={`${classes.ShopCard}__content`}>
                <Title title={title} size="h6" />
                <Body>{description}</Body>
            </div>

            <div className={`${classes.ShopCard}__button`}>
                <Button label="In winkelwagen" startIcon={<AddShoppingCart />} />
            </div>

            <CustomDialog
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                colsAmount={6}
                component={<ShopPopUp />}
                closeButton="true"
            />
        </div>
```

If someone could explain why the open state gets set to true, that would be great.

Comment: Problem seems to be the element that has the handleClickOpen event attached. For some reason that event doesn't get trigger when I for example attach it to the image instead of the component itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of:

`<div className={[classes.ShopCard]} onClick={handleClickOpen}>`

It exists higher up in the DOM than the overlay thus it always fires.